# Do you know of any Key-Value-Coding and Key-Value-Observing session videos on the net?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I know Apple is not the only ressource out there, and many people create great videos in conferences and presentations.

If someone knows a great video or podcast on the topics KVC or KVO, please let me know. I would be glad about it!

*Edit: Changed Title so it's more clear this is indeed programming related. KVO / KVC / MVC != [KFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kentucky_fried_chicken)*

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question as “not a real question”: KVC and KVO are programming things. This question is on-topic. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/ http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this one on KVC and Bindings over at Vimeo; http://vimeo.com/3635738

The 2009 Stanford iPhone Programming course discussed KVC and KVO in class 13. You can get that via the iTunes U store. I couldn't find that material in the 2010 class.

The MDN Show discusses many things and under it's previous name they did a show on the subject. Since most of those shows are available under the new name look for "Late Night Cocoa (035): KVC/KVO with Stefan Frey".